# Android Leanback PageRow Animation

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am building a Android TV application using the Leanback Support library using [PageRow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/PageRow.html)s.

I am following pretty much what the `leanback-showcase` same app is doing [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/page/PageAndListRowFragment.java), but I am wondering if it is possible to animate the fragments exiting and entering when the row changes?

It is pretty jolting when the fragments are changed for each row.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the official documentation, [android.support.v17.leanback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/package-summary.html) has [R.animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/R.animator.html) class. Then you may use the [`lb_playback_rows_fade_in`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/R.animator.html#lb_playback_rows_fade_in) and [`lb_playback_rows_fade_out`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/R.animator.html#lb_playback_rows_fade_out) methods.